# Clear In-Memory store type

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I would like to delete every previously saved object from Core Data. I am using the In-Memory store type so `NSBatchDeleteRequest` is not an option.

I tried calling `reset()` on the context but, it does not seem to do anything.

I have the following code:

```
viewContext.reset()
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CompactJobManaged> = CompactJobManaged.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "highlightedAt", ascending: false),
                                NSSortDescriptor(key: "uploadedAt", ascending: true)]
print(try! viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest).count)
```

I expect `print` statement on the bottom to print out 0 after calling `reset()` but instead, it prints out the number of objects that have been saved previously despite calling `reset()` before.

It is possible that I am misusing the `reset()` function for this purpose, but I do not know of any other ways to batch delete all objects from the In-Memory store.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```
do {
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStoreAtURL(persistentStoreURL, withType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)

} catch {
    // Error Handling
}
```